# removing list elements starting with octothorpe in python omits some elements

Tags: text-parsing, python-3.7

This is the text file (pathProtocol.txt):

```
# 2018-09-30
# incubator at 33C
# sample compartment at 32C
# hold sample in for 30sec before
# measurement

samp-2
reps-3

#Temp   Humid   Press
# 24    42  980

# background
MilliQ_MilliQ_0 000-005

Q_Prp_62mM  006-011
Q_Ah6_62mM  012-017
Q_Eth_62mM  018-023
Q_AcA_62mM  024-029
Q_Imd_62mM  030-035

# background
MilliQ_MilliQ_0 036-041
# 24    43  977
```

that I'm parsing and from which I'm trying to remove blank and lines starting with a #.
Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842057/easiest-way-to-ignore-blank-lines-when-reading-a-file-in-python) my code starts with:

```
# PROTOCOL PARSING
# READ FILE & EXCLUDE BLANKS
with open(os.path.join(*pathProtocol)) as f:
    content = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    # Non-blank lines in a list
    content = list(line for line in content if line)
#
print(content)
print(type(content))
print(len(content))
print('')
```

yielding the desired output:

```
['# 2018-09-30', '# incubator at 33C', '# sample compartment at 32C', '# hold sample in for 30sec before', '# measurement', 'samp-2', 'reps-3', '#Temp   Humid\tPress', '# 24\t42\t980', '# background', 'MilliQ_MilliQ_0\t000-005', 'Q_Prp_62mM\t006-011', 'Q_Ah6_62mM\t012-017', 'Q_Eth_62mM\t018-023', 'Q_AcA_62mM\t024-029', 'Q_Imd_62mM\t030-035', '# background', 'MilliQ_MilliQ_0\t036-041', '# 24\t43\t977']
<class 'list'>
19
```

The interesting part starts when I try to remove lines starting with octothrope from the above created list ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985783/use-python-to-remove-lines-in-a-files-that-start-with-an-octothorpe)):

```
# DELETE COMMENTS
for i, line in enumerate(content):
    print(str(i), line, '\tfirst char:', line[0])
    if line.startswith('#'):
        content.remove(line)
    #
#
print(content)
```

I get the following output:

```
0 # 2018-09-30  first char: #
1 # sample compartment at 32C   first char: #
2 # measurement     first char: #
3 reps-3    first char: r
4 #Temp   Humid Press   first char: #
5 # background  first char: #
6 Q_Prp_62mM    006-011     first char: Q
7 Q_Ah6_62mM    012-017     first char: Q
8 Q_Eth_62mM    018-023     first char: Q
9 Q_AcA_62mM    024-029     first char: Q
10 Q_Imd_62mM   030-035     first char: Q
11 # background     first char: #
12 # 24 43  977     first char: #
['# incubator at 33C', '# hold sample in for 30sec before', 'samp-2', 'reps-3', '# 24\t42\t980', 'MilliQ_MilliQ_0\t000-005', 'Q_Prp_62mM\t006-011', 'Q_Ah6_62mM\t012-017', 'Q_Eth_62mM\t018-023', 'Q_AcA_62mM\t024-029', 'Q_Imd_62mM\t030-035', 'MilliQ_MilliQ_0\t036-041']
```

that omits some items from the initial list but shows them in the subsequent list output. I just can't wrap my head around what's going on in line-by-line output (as a python beginner). What is the mistake I'm making ? How can I correctly remove lines starting with # ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing `content` while you're iterating over it, which generally doesn't work.
Instead, iterate over a *copy* of `content`. That is, change `enumerate(content)` to `enumerate(content[:])`.